# C++ '+' concatenation operator changing contents of pointers in pointer vector

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector, c-strings

So I wanted to write a program that did the following:

- Accept a string input from user using std::getline(std::cin,str)
- Append this input to `std::string object` using `+` operator
- Initial value of `object` is `object="\n"`
- After user inputs a line and it is appended to `object` , add a `'\n'` to object
- so for example, if `hello` is entered in console ,then `object="\nhello\n"`
- if `my` is entered on next line then `object="\nhello\nmy\n"`, so on and so forth.

Now i have also declared a `std::vector<const char*> lines` which points to all the `\n` characters in `object`

In we take the example given in the last bullet point, `lines` has 3 elements pointing to `\n` characters

The code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<const char*> lines;
    std::string object = "\n";
    lines.push_back(object.c_str());
    std::string temp;
    int object_size;
    while (std::getline(std::cin,temp))
    {
        object_size = object.length();
        object = object + temp;
        object = object + "\n";
        lines.push_back(object.c_str() + object_size + temp.size());//pointers in this point to all the \n characters

    }

}
```

Now coming to the problem:

So after inputting

```
hello
name
is
```

and checking the values of lines and object in the watch window of vs 2019 integrated debugger, it shows

```
object="\nhello\nname\nis\n"
lines[0]=0x0082fb04"\nhello\nname\nis\n"                \\points to first \n
lines[1]=0x0082fb0a"\nname\nis\n"                        \\points to second \n
lines[2]=0x0082fb0f"\nis\n"                               \\points to third \n
lines[3]=0x0082fb12"\n"                                    \\points to last \n
```

which makes sense as there are 4 `\n` in `object`.

now I input `xyzabc` in the next line, so the console looks like:

```
hello
name
is
xyzabc
```

In the while loop, everything is fine until the line
`object=object+temp;`

As soon as `object=object+temp;` is executed, the debugger shows:

```
object="\nhello\nname\nis\nxyzabc"       \\object does not end with \n because object = object + "\n" has not been executed yet
lines[0]=0x0082fb04 "pù\x4\x1lo\nname\nis"
lines[1]=0x0082fb0a "\nname\nis"
lines[2]=0x0082fb1f "\nis"
lines[3]=0x0082fb12""
```

Value of `object` is as expected but the contents to which pointers in `lines` point to has been modified just by the line `object=object+temp`
expected values after executing that line were:

```
object="\nhello\nname\nis\nxyzabc"
lines[0]=0x0082fb04"\nhello\nname\nis\nxyzabc"                
lines[1]=0x0082fb0a"\nname\nis\nxyzabc"                        
lines[2]=0x0082fb0f"\nis\nxyzabc"                               
lines[3]=0x0082fb12"\nxyzabc"
```

Why is this happening? and how do append I `object` and `temp` without facing this problem?

Comment: When you expand your string it may need to relocate the data. All iterators (and your pointers) then become invalid. Store indexes instead of pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object` is likely to be reallocated as you concatenate stuff into it. This means the pointers to its content in `lines` are invalidated. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: so is there any way i can concatenate other strings into object without having to face this problem,thanks.

Comment: @SwarajSonavane Store indexes instead of pointers.

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner and I am not sure what you mean by 'indexes'

Comment: Store the positions in the string where `\n` is placed instead of pointers.

Comment: Also, couldn't you just store each line separately in a `std::vector<std::string> lines;` and go with it? Or do you specifically need 1 single `std::string` buffer to store everything contiguously?

Comment: @m88 The exercise I was solving required me to store everything in one std::string buffer

Answer (score 1):

Both, `object + temp;` and `object + "\n";` are fine and do the right thing: concatenate the strings. However, this is not correct:

```
lines.push_back(object.c_str() + object_size + temp.size());
```

Because ([cppreference::string::c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str))...

> Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data
> equivalent to those stored in the string.
>
> The pointer is such that the range [c_str(); c_str() + size()] is
> valid and the values in it correspond to the values stored in the
> string with an additional null character after the last position.
>
> The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and
>   rend().

The pointer returned from `c_str` is not meant to be stored independend of the string. If you want to store strings in the vector (instead of invalid pointers) you should be using a `std::vector<std::string>`.